# package installation error, with respect to username

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, anaconda, anaconda3

I'm currently setting up a conda environment using Windows 10.

My username was in Korean, so I changed it to my initials to prevent a Unicode error.

After downloading Anaconda, when I try to install packages on my environment, this error comes out:

```
# >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ERROR REPORT <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\CHJ\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\conda\exception_handler.py", line 17, in __call__
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "C:\Users\CHJ\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 54, in main_subshell
        parser = generate_parser(add_help=True)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "C:\Users\CHJ\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\conda\cli\conda_argparse.py", line 127, in generate_parser
        configure_parser_plugins(sub_parsers)
      File "C:\Users\CHJ\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\conda\cli\conda_argparse.py", line 354, in configure_parser_plugins
        else set(find_commands()).difference(plugin_subcommands)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "C:\Users\CHJ\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\conda\cli\find_commands.py", line 71, in find_commands
        for entry in os.scandir(dir_path):
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    OSError: [WinError 123] 파일 이름, 디렉터리 이름 또는 볼륨 레이블 구문이 잘못되었습니다: 'C:\\Users\\?뺥쁽議?AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Microsoft VS Code\\bin'
```

The same thing happens for `conda list` or `conda install package-name`, in any environment.

I suspect that this is because of my former username, but I don't know how to fix it.

---

```
OSError: [WinError 123] 파일 이름, 디렉터리 이름 또는 볼륨 레이블 구문이 잘못되었습니다: 'C:\\Users\\?뺥쁽議?AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Microsoft VS Code\\bin'
```

translates to:

```
OSError: [WinError 123] Syntax for the file name, directory name, or volume label is incorrect: 'C:\\Users\\?뺥쁽議?AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Microsoft VS Code\\bin'
```

If I do the same with the administrator account, the error disappears.
It only happens in my user account.

Comment: The error is most probably because of the change from Korean to initials. Please follow [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1346983) to rename the user profile in Windows to reflect the new username (your initials). But, keep in mind it may cause issues with some other programs that rely on this path.